# End a task that has a ui updated inside the task C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have the following code:

```
void Selection()
    {
        bool solutionFound = false;
        int generation = 0;
        int distance = int.MaxValue;

        while(!solutionFound)
        {
            generation++;
            for (int i = 0; i < population.Length; i++)
            {
                population[i].CalcFitness(target);
            }

            matingPool = new List<DNA>();

            for (int i = 0; i < population.Length; i++)
            {
                int n = (int)(population[i].fitness * 100);
                for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                {
                    matingPool.Add(population[i]);
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < population.Length; i++)
            {
                int a = StaticRandom.Instance.Next(matingPool.Count);
                int b = StaticRandom.Instance.Next(matingPool.Count);
                DNA partnerA = matingPool[a];
                DNA partnerB = matingPool[b];

                if(partnerA.GetPhrase().Equals(partnerB.GetPhrase()))
                {
                    while(partnerA.GetPhrase().Equals(partnerB.GetPhrase()))
                    {
                        a = StaticRandom.Instance.Next(matingPool.Count);
                        b = StaticRandom.Instance.Next(matingPool.Count);
                        partnerA = matingPool[a];
                        partnerB = matingPool[b];
                    }
                }
                DNA child = partnerA.Crossover(partnerB);
                child.Mutate(mutationRate);
                population[i] = child;

                ThreadHelperClass.SetText(this, display_lbl, i + ": " + child.GetPhrase());
                ThreadHelperClass.SetText(this, gen_lbl, "Generations: " + generation);
                int compute = LevenshteinDistance.Compute(target, child.GetPhrase());

                if(compute < distance)
                {
                    distance = compute;
                    ThreadHelperClass.SetText(this, bestPhrase_lbl, "Best Phrase: " + child.GetPhrase());
                }

                if(child.GetPhrase().Equals(target))
                {
                    solutionFound = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and the following code

```
public static class ThreadHelperClass
{
    delegate void SetTextCallback(Form f, Control ctrl, string t);

    public static void SetText(Form form, Control control, string text)
    {
        //Invoke requires compares the thread ID of the calling thread
        //to the thread ID of the creating thread
        //If they are different InvokeRequired sets to true
        if (control.InvokeRequired)
        {
            SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText);
            form.Invoke(d, new Object[] { form, control, text });
        }
        else
            control.Text = text;
    }
}
```

I send Selection to another thread using:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Selection(), cToken.Token);
```

I've already tried to set the ThreadHelper class to use `BeginInvoke` instead of `Invoke` and it locks up my UI on the first iteration of the Selection method.
I've also tried to end the task using `cToken.Cancel()`. This still locks up my UI when the user clicks the stop_btn.

Is there a way I can stop this from happening?

Comment: Are you sure that the while loop does not run endless, means `if(child.GetPhrase().Equals(target))` will become true anytime?

Comment: yes but the `child.Mutate(mutationRate)` prevents that from happening... and it's /supposed/ to do that until it finds a solution. What's going wrong is the problem above.

Comment: Are you sure that you don't have too much cross-threading overhead. If your code calls `ThreadHelperClass.SetText` thousands of time, it might be a bottleneck.

Comment: @Phil1970 why would that cause a UI lock up?

Comment: Switching thread is very slow and if the background code run faster than cross-thread + UI update, then essentially UI will stop responding as the UI thread will be busy 100% of the time with tread switching and UI updates. As a rule of the thumb, usually I would update the UI once each percent of work done (for a processing between a few seconds and up to about a minute). In your case, you do 3 such cross-thread update so if it is the bottleneck then your code would be 3 times slower.

Comment: @Phil1970 I don't understand how that makes sense... If the background code is done executing and the UI thread is only performing updates then how is it locked?! It's perfoming updates.

Comment: The background thread can call `Invoke` at a much higher rate that what the UI thread is able to process given inter-thread communication and switch time so essentially as soon as the UI has done one update, then the other update is ready. Also, actual repainting of the UI has a low priority so the UI won't be refreshed when it is busy doing something else. And if the UI thread if very busy, then it won't respond timely to user (or the UI won't be immediately updated)... **To see by yourself, you can try to call `Invoke` in a loop 1000 times. Then try 10000 times and so on.**